# rails read the file and store the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
       i saved  .rb file in app/component/text.rb. i want to read and store the database.
```

in that file has 5 rows and my table also have 5 rows.i want to save line by line.you can understand my question.i use mysql database.

```
  please help me....
```

thanks,
kingston.s

Comment: I understand that language might be a barrier here, but perhaps you can do a bit better in explaining your problem. Right now this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the rails- and ruby-version, the operating system you use and a clear problem description...anyway

Assuming that you meant your database would have 5 fields and you want to read and write a record to a file:

Assuming the file will contain a record for the model "Apple "with the fields id, title and description.

Read new Apple from file:

```
indexes = [:id, :title, :desc].reverse # be careful the data will be saved reverse because pop takes the last element first
record_params = {}

handle = File.open("Apple.record","r")
handle.lines.each do |line|
  record_params[indexes.pop]=line.chomp #use chomp to get rid of the trailing \n
end
handle.close

Apple.create!(record_params)
```

Write Apple with id 7 to a File

```
indexes = [:id, :title, :desc]
record = Apple.find(7)
to_save = indexes.map{|i| record.send i}

handle = File.open("Apple.record","w")
handle.write(to_save.join("\n"))
handle.close
```

Beware to escape the linebreaks in your data if there are any possible..

Anyway it would be much easier to use YAML:

```
#write the first apple to the file
handle = File.open("Apple.record", "w")
handle = Apple.first.to_yaml
handle.close

#read the file to a new record
record_params = YAML.load File.read("Apple.record")
Apple.create!(record_params)
```

All this worked in Rails 3, but remember, that you are saving the id as well, therefore saving and loading will cause the id to change, because a record with the given id already existed.